# Ubuntu 17.10 wifi issues

Tags: networking, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 510 and upon installing 17.10 I've been having consistent wifi issues.

Primary the randomly dropping the wifi connection and the problems associated with that.

I've tried multiple "fixes" but none of them work, I even purchased a USB wifi adapter to try and bypass the issue but to no avail.

Does anyone have a fix?

Edit #1:

Running `nlspci -knn | grep Net -A3` gives the following output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
03:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] [10de:134d] (rev a2)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. Replace `lspci` with `lsusb` if you want to troubleshoot the new USB dongle. That said, the symptoms occuring with two very different chipset (supposedly) suggests you have wrong wireless encryption settings at the router.

Comment: Same issues on Dell XPS13:
 3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
 Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
 Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
 Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have the same laptop and had this issue with 16.04, 17.04 and 17.10 versions of ubuntu.
The following solution fixed mine.

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```

and restart. Hope this fix the issue.

Comment: So what commands do I have to run to install this? I got to "cd rtlwifi_new" before I got lost. (Sorry, linux newbie here)

Comment: These are the commands in the greyed zone. Enter one by one

Comment: Oops! Sorry, everything was showing as plain text, my bad!

Comment: Let me know when you try it.

Comment: You're actually a godsend. Thank you so so so much, I can finally ditch windows now! Thank you so much!